# Exchange FindItem responding with different set of properties for one item id and for multiple item ids

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

When I loading properties of multiple exchange items by `ExchangeService.LoadPropertiesForItems` method, Exchange skip some properties of items attachments in response:

```
<t:CalendarItem>
  <t:ItemId Id="itemId" ChangeKey="itemChangeKey"/>
  <t:Subject>Test appointment</t:Subject>
  <t:Attachments>
    <t:FileAttachment>
      <t:AttachmentId Id="firstAttachmentId"/>
      <t:Name>pdf.pdf</t:Name>
      <t:Size>94150</t:Size>
      <t:LastModifiedTime>2015-08-03T10:54:40</t:LastModifiedTime>
      <t:IsInline>false</t:IsInline>
      <t:IsContactPhoto>false</t:IsContactPhoto>
    </t:FileAttachment>
    <t:FileAttachment>
      <t:AttachmentId Id="secondAttachmentId"/>
      <t:Name>ATT89202</t:Name>
      <t:Size>3803738</t:Size>
      <t:LastModifiedTime>2015-12-03T16:40:46</t:LastModifiedTime>
      <t:IsInline>true</t:IsInline>
    </t:FileAttachment>
  </t:Attachments>
</t:CalendarItem>
```

As you can see, in response above not included `ContentId` property.
But when I use `Load` method of `Item` class for loading properties of single item, EWS Managed API generates the same `GetItem` SOAP request with single item id and Exchange responding with extended set of attachments properties:

```
<t:CalendarItem>
  <t:ItemId Id="itemId" ChangeKey="itemChangeKey"/>
  <t:Subject>Test appointment</t:Subject>
  <t:Attachments>
    <t:FileAttachment>
      <t:AttachmentId Id="firstAttachmentId"/>
      <t:Name>pdf.pdf</t:Name>
      <t:ContentId>25F20E449DEC42B67EB3DE58C51E56E3BE0B27F5@1</t:ContentId>
      <t:Size>94150</t:Size>
      <t:LastModifiedTime>2015-08-03T10:54:40</t:LastModifiedTime>
      <t:IsInline>false</t:IsInline>
      <t:IsContactPhoto>false</t:IsContactPhoto>
    </t:FileAttachment>
    <t:FileAttachment>
      <t:AttachmentId Id="secondAttachmentId"/>
      <t:Name>ATT89202</t:Name>
      <t:ContentId>DB969CA378C5F9565E98779626E3BCA3A65FB275@1</t:ContentId>
      <t:Size>3803738</t:Size>
      <t:LastModifiedTime>2015-12-03T16:40:46</t:LastModifiedTime>
      <t:IsInline>true</t:IsInline>
    </t:FileAttachment>
  </t:Attachments>
</t:CalendarItem>
```

As you can see, in the second response `ContentId` property presented
Moreover, when I use `ExchangeService.LoadPropertiesForItems` method, passing in single item as the first argument, Exchange also include `Attachment.ContentId` property into response.

Is there a way I can get `ContentId` properties of items attachments without loading properties for all items separately?

Comment: have you tried service.LoadPropertiesForItems(items, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);?

Comment: @kienct89 yes, I tried. The same result - if there is single item in collection, Exchange responding with `ContentId` property of inline attachments. If there are more than one item passed in, `ContentId` does not returned for attachments of all items.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ExchangeService.BindToItems` method. It returns a comprehensive set of attachment properties.

See
[ExchangeService.BindToItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.bindtoitems(v=exchg.80).aspx)

Comment: The same result - ContentId property not returned

Comment: Maybe you could try the [EWS GetAttachment operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa494316(v=exchg.150).aspx) so you can send a list of all attachement ids you want to load together. I realize it is not exactly what you want but it beats making multiple calls for each attachment you retrieve. Hopefully it works.